# Objectmapper writeValueAsString throwing OOM Exception

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

I'm repeatedly converting an object to a String using the Jackson writeValueAsString method, like a couple of thousand times repeatedly. The size of JSON would be something around 1KB. But after a while, my program exits and throws OOM Exception. Following is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.carr(TextBuffer.java:864)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.expand(TextBuffer.java:825)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.append(TextBuffer.java:590)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SegmentedStringWriter.write(SegmentedStringWriter.java:58)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._writeString2(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:1013)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._writeString(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:982)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeString(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:377)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:41)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:718)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:639)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:33)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3893)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3207)
        at com.ad2pro.neonmigration.neondatamigration.utils.NeonMetricsProducerUtil.produceImpressions(NeonMetricsProducerUtil.java:121)
        at com.ad2pro.neonmigration.neondatamigration.scheduler.NeonScheduler.gerMetrics(NeonScheduler.java:100)
        at com.ad2pro.neonmigration.neondatamigration.NeonDataMigrationApplication.main(NeonDataMigrationApplication.java:18)
        ... 8 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:814)
        at javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineUpdate(CipherSpi.java:555)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:2002)
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:544)
        at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.decrypt(EngineInputRecord.java:200)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:974)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at com.amazon.support.channels.TLSSocketChannel.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesThread.run(Unknown Source)
~
```

There is 1GB of free memory before my program starts. Is objectmapper holding onto a lot of memory that even 1GB is not sufficient to convert objects to String. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One thing to check for is whether the object has any nested properties resulting in infinite-loop...typically this happens when marshalling JPA/Hibernate entities with bi-directional relationships.

Comment: You need to show your code, probably you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set JVM  heap passing the parameters -Xmx and -Xms. For example tell to the Jvm to take a maximium of 512 mb of heap -Xms512m.

Default max heap size is 64 mb, maybe that's not enough for your program.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple aspects to this issue:

1. As mentioned in above answer ,Increase the JVM heap to take 512 mb.
2. Check whether conversion to String using objectMapper object is not
   created everytime it is called.
3. writeAsString should not result in unending string.
4. use visualVM and check what exactly is causing increase in heap.